# Iterating a ConcurrentHashMap in correct order

Tags: java, data-structures

I use a `ConcurrentHashMap` to store English words and their occurrences within a text.

```
private Map<String, Integer> _vocab = new ConcurrentHashMap<String,Integer>();
```

I need the map to be sorted by the value in descending order, so I did:

```
   public void sort(){
        this._vocab = this._vocab.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()))
                .collect(
                        toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (e1, e2) -> e2,
                                LinkedHashMap::new));
    }
```

Which seems to be working. However, now I want to limit the hashmap to for example 1000 elements, since I'm only interested in the top 1000 entries:

```
public void limitToNElements(int n){
    ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer> res = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer>();

    Iterator it = this._vocab.entrySet().iterator();
    int i = 0;
    while (it.hasNext() && i < n) {
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        String word = (String)pair.getKey();
        res.put((String)pair.getKey(), (Integer)pair.getValue());

        i += 1;
    }

    this._vocab = res;
}
```

The problem is, that the iterator is not iterating in the correct order, but rather randomly.

So I read that only `LinkedHashMaps` work this way, but since there is no Concurrent version and I'm afraid to do the synchronization myself, I'm wondering if there is any workaround to achieve what I want?

Edit:
I used a HashMap because insertion/occurrence counting was very simple:

```
for(String word: input){
  this._vocab.put(word, this._vocab.getOrDefault(word, 0)+1);
}
```

Comment: possible hint: `ConcurrentHashMap` why? See https://ideone.com/5jYACH

Comment: I'm inserting the elements to the HashMap within a `.parallelStream().forEach()`

Comment: Not clear why you're using a `ConcurrentHashMap` to begin with, but more importantly, if you want the 'top 1000 entries' of something, the data structure in which you want to store that is probably not a `Map` anyway. Just put the entries themselves into something ordered, like a `List`.

Comment: I used a HashMap because insertion/occurrence counting was very simple, and possible without iteration, see edit

Comment: You probably want to look at some examples of this, since it's a really common problem and often used as a demo for use of the various libraries. It's hard to tell exactly what you're after but as shown, your implementation seems way more complicated than it needs to be (and what's with all the casting, suddenly?). Start with a basic (non-parallel) example, get it working and go from there, if you run into concrete problems, post about those.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just apply `limit` on the stream:

```
public void sort() {
    this._vocab = this._vocab.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()))
            .limit(1000) // Here
            .collect(
                    toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (e1, e2) -> e2,
                            LinkedHashMap::new));
}
```

Comment: That seems to mostly mask the fundamental problem which is that after sorting, the results are, inexplicably, destructured back into a map again for no particular reason, given the goals of the poster.